# What is the definition of "center" or "kernel" of a set in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In the text I'm reading the author says:

> We also define the kernel of $K\subseteq X$ ($X$ a Banach space) to be the set
> $$
> \overset{c}{K}:=\{x\in K:\forall y\in X\exists a>0\text{ with }\lambda y+(1-\lambda)x\in K,\text{ for all }0\leq\lambda\leq a\}.
> $$
> Sometimes it is called the "center" of $K$.

However, in numerous proofs in the text (chapter really), the author shows some point is in the center of a set and I don't follow why; for instance, the following part of a proof:

Consider the function $\mu\colon X\to[0,\infty)$ with the property $\mu(\lambda x)=\lambda\mu(x)$ for any $\lambda\geq0$. Consider the set $M:=\{x:\mu(x)\leq1\}$. The author claims that $0\in\overset{c}{M}$ since $\mu(\lambda x)=\lambda\mu(x)$. I don't see why. I mean, because of $\mu(\lambda x)=\lambda\mu(x)$ it follows that $\mu(0)=0\leq1$, so $0\in M$. Therefore take $x:=0\in M$ and any $y\in X$. By definition of the set $\overset{c}{M}$, our goal is to show there exists $a>0$ with $\lambda y+(1-\lambda)x\in M=\{x:\mu(x)\leq1\}$ for all $0\leq\lambda\leq a$.

Since $x=0$, this means we want to show there exists $a>0$ with $\lambda y\in\{x:\mu(x)\leq1\}$ for all $0\leq\lambda\leq a$. Or rather there exists $a>0$ with $\mu(\lambda y)=\lambda\mu(y)\leq 1$ for all $0\leq\lambda\leq a$. This doesn't need to hold for every $y\in X$, though right? I believe we need the restriction that $y\in M$, thus the definition for the kernel would change to
$$
\overset{c}{K}:=\{x\in K:\forall y\in K\exists a>0\text{ with }\lambda y+(1-\lambda)x\in K,\text{ for all }0\leq\lambda\leq a\}.
$$
Therefore if we knew that $y\in M$, then $\mu(y)\leq1$, and we could take $a=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say $\forall \, y \, \exists \, a$ you are allowing $a$ to depend on $y$.  $\lambda \mu (y) \leq 1$ for $0\leq \lambda \leq a$ certainly holds for some $a$ depending on $y$.

Comment: I see. I forgot that by the order of the quantifiers the $a$ value may depend on the $y$ in $X$. Thus taking $a:=1/\mu(y)$ the result holds.